Is it possible to access the SQL statement that caused the delete trigger to fire?
I have defined an AFTER DELETE SQL trigger on a table and I want to store information in another table. Therefore, I would like to also store the SQL statement that triggered the trigger. Is there a way to access this statement? Or something similar? I just don't want to retrieve all that information by hand. Also, I might want to use the trigger on different tables.
I googled a lot, and only found EVENTDATA() for logon-triggers and COLUMNS_UPDATED(), but nothing related to delete triggers.

No, you can't access the statement that caused the trigger to fire; if you need logging, there are plenty of other options. This is what we call an XY Problem.

Just use your application that executes the delete command to log it. As you know which conditions cause the trigger to be fired, you can simply check these conditions there.

Perhaps you can use trace / events / query store to retreive the delete statements and correlate it either inside the trigger or afterwards, but sounds complicated. you might use dbcc inputbuffer(xxx) to get the original statement, but it might not be the actual delete, plus, you usually need systemadmin rights for reading that.

thanks everybody. I'm partly glad I didn't miss something obvious ;)
Unfortunately I don't have access to the application, that's why I'm using a trigger in the first place.
Since I know the structure of the table the easy choice is to log the data manually then. Thanks again :)

XEvents is probably what you are looking for. You can trace sql_statement_completed events and correlate it with the execution of the trigger using batch_completed events

SQL Audit essentially allows you to track when a given permission (that is, the combination of grant and securable) is invoked, by whom, when, and (importantly for this question) how. Needing to grab the statement on an ongoing and long-term basis seems excessive to me, but I'm not you.

The similar question "Is it possible to get execution call stack in a trigger?" Database Administrators Stack Exchange might be worth a read.  The options are very limited. One involves systematically setting CONTEXT_INFO() at the start of a SQL execution. (Perhaps an interceptor could inject a statement to set caller information before execution.) I don't think any options give you exactly what you are looking for, but they might be useful alternatives.
